# fetch data into datagridview from textbox's selected text

Tags: c#

In textbox I am fetching city name and when I select any city name, information related to that city should display on datagridview, to fetch other information about the state I used a foreign key because state table is different and its information is stored in another table so I fetch that information from foreign key state_id. Here is my code

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter tda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT a1.type,a1.state_id,a1.desc1,a1.from_date,a1.to_date,a1.expr1005 FROM item_rate a1 FULL OUTER JOIN item_rate_state a2 ON a1.state_id=a2.state_id WHERE state_name='" + textBox2.Text + "'", scon);
            tda.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a clear question in what you've posted

Comment: ok i have table name item_rate_state in which i 've only 2 columns i.e.state_id,state_name related to items.Now i've another table item_rate in which i 've multiple columns those stores information about items,now when i search state into textbox,and if i select any resultant state the information of items related that state from item_rate table should get fetch on datagridview but not all information,only the column i m trying to select in above query should get fetched in datagridview

Answer (score 1):

The query seems a little wrong

it should be

```
SqlDataAdapter tda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT a1.type,a1.state_id,a1.desc1,a1.from_date,a1.to_date,a1.expr1005 FROM item_rate a1 FULL OUTER JOIN item_rate_state a2 ON a1.state_id=a2.state_id WHERE a2.state_name='" + textBox2.Text + "'", scon);
```

i would suggest you to use `SqlCommand` and add parameters to query proper way as your code is vulnerable to sql injection!

---

Answer as per the comment.

since you do now want to show any record when textbox is empty simple on `TextChanged` event do this

```
if (!String.IsNotNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
{

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter tda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT a1.type,a1.state_id,a1.desc1,a1.from_date,a1.to_date,a1.expr1005 FROM item_rate a1 FULL OUTER JOIN item_rate_state a2 ON a1.state_id=a2.state_id WHERE a2.state_name='" + textBox2.Text + "'", scon);
    tda.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;

}
```

Comment: no actually the result that is desirable to me is getting fetched in datagridview,the problem is that when i write above code on textbox_keypress event or any any other event when i select that state fetched into textbox and press backspace button twice that time it get fetched which i dont want.

Answer (score 0):

You have Try like this

Set `textBox2.AutoPostBack="True"` in design page

```
 protected void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter tda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT a1.type,a1.state_id,a1.desc1,a1.from_date,a1.to_date,a1.expr1005 FROM item_rate a1 FULL OUTER JOIN item_rate_state a2 ON a1.state_id=a2.state_id WHERE state_name='" + textBox2.Text + "'", scon);
            tda.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

Comment: `TextChanged` would be fired for every text change guess not something the OP desires.

Comment: then try this in Button click event

Comment: no i cant since there is some protocol which i have to follow.

Comment: Okay then this is the right way i think. then set condition there like if string length is greater then some digit then data bind will fire..